# PhpStorm terminal is inactive

Tags: terminal, phpstorm

I use phpstrorm 7. I used the terminal for a while. Now, with no known reason the terminal is always inactive.[image]

has anybody faced similar situation? any explanation or solution?

Edit: I can't get auto complete on variable typing

Edit: this is my [idea.log](https://gist.github.com/eiwanarts/7657331)

Comment: please can you attach your idea.log (Help/Show log in Explorer)?

Comment: here is it https://gist.github.com/eiwanarts/7657331

Comment: I see, thanks for update:) known issue - see [PY-10548](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10548)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue - see [PY-10548](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10548)
Please try updating to the most recent PHPStorm EAP (http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) - the issue should be fixed there

Comment: Thank you. doing it. I will let you know

Comment: the terminal is fixed. But I still can't get autocomplete :(

Comment: auto completion was disabled because I chose "Power save mode".

Answer (score 1):

another answer by myself :)

the auto completion feature was disabled because I chose the "power save mode"

Frankly I think this "power save mode" is rediculous feature; how much power do you guys think you are saving :P

Comment: It all counts when you're away and without a power source!